# Connect kubectl to Google Compute Engine Kubernetes installation

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have followed [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/#inspect-your-cluster) for installing Kubernetes using googles web shell.

Now if I would like to use the Terminal on Mac, how do I connect `kubectl` to the master GCE - I can not use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]` as I did not creatre a `Cluster engine` but installed Kubernetes via `cluster/kube-up.sh`

Do you know how to connect `kubectl` from Mac terminal to the installation on Google Compute Engine?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? Are you searching for a way to [deploy a containerized application in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart)? Here [kubectl](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart#creating_the_deployment) is being used to create a deployment.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question - hopw it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl` gets it's configuration from a "kubeconfig" file, usually `~/.kube/config`. This file is written by `kube-up.sh`, so if you used kube-up on a different system you should be able to copy the kubeconfig file from that machine to your Mac and then use `kubectl` normally.